# Need Support for Apple Pencil/Finger drawing on Swift 3

Tags: swift3, core-graphics, swift2, ios10.3, xcode8

I am making use of swift 2.3 with [TouchCanvas](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TouchCanvas/Introduction/Intro.html) (Apple Pencil Sample App),

in which while drawing,

I am able to switch between pen/pencil/brush/eraser - thickness & colors and the same is applied correspondingly.

Ref: [image: Screen1_Swift2.3_vs_Swift3.0.png]

Now I upgraded to swift 3.0,

in which which drawing,

when switch between pen/pencil/brush/eraser - thickness & colors, the last picked one is applied to ALL.

Ref:[image: Screen2_Swift2.3_vs_Swift3.0.png]

and also tried apple latest [pencil](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeedSketch/Introduction/Intro.html) API..Results were same

can please any one tell me exact solution for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhhh...After trying long hours ...found an solution..

Just one line  on CanvasView.swift

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        context.setLineCap(.round)
```

> needsFullRedraw = false //Added this line

```
        if (needsFullRedraw) {
            setFrozenImageNeedsUpdate()
            frozenContext.clear(bounds)
           for array in [finishedLines,lines] {
                for line in array {
                    line.drawCommitedPointsInContext(frozenContext, isDebuggingEnabled: isDebuggingEnabled, usePreciseLocation: usePreciseLocations)

                }

            }
            needsFullRedraw = false
        }

        frozenImage = frozenImage ?? frozenContext.makeImage()

        if let frozenImage = frozenImage {
            context.draw(frozenImage, in: bounds)
        }

     for line in lines {
            line.drawInContext(context, isDebuggingEnabled: isDebuggingEnabled, usePreciseLocation: usePreciseLocations)

        }

    }
```

or just commented the following line

```
/*if (needsFullRedraw) {
                setFrozenImageNeedsUpdate()
                frozenContext.clear(bounds)
               for array in [finishedLines,lines] {
                    for line in array {
                        line.drawCommitedPointsInContext(frozenContext, isDebuggingEnabled: isDebuggingEnabled, usePreciseLocation: usePreciseLocations)

                    }

                }
                needsFullRedraw = false
            }*/
```